# clustering evaluation, taking into account the number of cluster

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining

I know how to calculate the Recall, Precision and F_measure for clusters as explained in this course https://www.coursera.org/learn/cluster-analysis/lecture/BcYhV/6-4-external-measures-1-matching-based-measures

However, what if the number of clusters generated by my system is more than the number of clusters in the ground-truth, how can we calculate these measures?

It seems that there is no penalty for systems generating more clusters since we just matching each cluster in the ground-truth to the best cluster generated from my system. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't compute them as in classification!!!

Either you need to work with pairs of points - that is the most common approach, used by the very popular ARI measure.

Or you need to find the cluster with the maximum overlap, this then sometimes called "matching". I am not convinced of this approach.

Last but not least, you could use the Hungarian algorithm to find the best partial 1:1 correspondence, and consider unmatched clusters to be all false.

Comment: Thanks for this. Thats what I am doing the matching measure. I found  the cluster with the maximum overlap and compute the recall and precision. But this does not take into consideration whether my system generates ten or fifteen clusters when the ground-truth clusters are (lets say seven clusters). Thats my question, the number of generated clusters are not considered in the evaluation !!

Comment: ... and that is why the matching approach is frowned upon. Use pairs.